# something between int and float to reserve less memory than with float?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, malloc

I need to save on(malloc) memory(ram) data who has the next form:

```
34566,5
45,5
46,67
32
-4
58
-43,5
etc
```

I mean, the data will never have more than 2 digit after the comma.
Somehow i can reserve memory without use the float type?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: sure if you never need more than +/- 2^31/100 then just use an int and know that the last 2 decimal digits are implicitly after the decimal... watch out for multiplication and division which will move that.

Comment: In a typical case, a float is exactly the *same* size as an `int` (both 32 bits in most cases). You could use a scaled `int` (i.e., store the original number multiplied by 100), though whether that's worthwhile depends heavily on what you need to do with them.

Comment: It also greatly matters what you want to achieve. Do those numbers (and arithmetic on them) need to be 100% precise? Do they need to be very big?

Comment: Once you've got them stored, what kind of access will you need?  If you don't need constant-time random access there are a lot of compression options available.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the number of digits BEFORE the comma.  If you know the total number of possible values, N, then you'll need ceiling(log2 N) bit values to be able to represent them all.  From that, you can figure out the smallest type that will fit in.

Answer (score 0):

If you really care about memory and if you are able to specify how many bits exactly you need to store single value, you can decide whether use built-in type or create your own. I mean, if you for example need 6 bits to store single value, you can make container that will store every  4 values using 3 bytes (3x char). Such containter had to use bit operators to access values.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a 16-bit integer would not suffice, so the next commonly available data type is a 32-bit integer or float, which means that there is probably no native data type that would save memory in this case. You could come up with a custom fixed point type that uses less bits (e.g., 24 bits would probably be the easiest; you'd store the number multiplied by 100 in an integer of three bytes), but overall I would suggest looking at ways to compress the whole dataset on the fly.